# How does requiring modules manually differ from calling them dynamically with browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Sorry for the awkward post title but it's a very weird situation to be in. In my project I have a folder structure like so:

```
/filters
     index.js
     [...]
/controllers
     index.js
     [...]
app.js
```

`app.js` is basically the entry point of my application and I thought it would be cool if I could automatically load the contents of those directories by `require()`ing the directory and having `index.js` in each of those directories take care of loading whatever it needs to load.

But I'm running into a problem I don't understand. Because I'm being intentionally obtuse (this is a learning/experimentation exercise) I decided to try and keep it as DRY as humanly possible so I tried this big of code to handle the module loading:

```
'use strict';

var customModules = [
    'controllers',
    'filters'
];

//require('./controllers');
//require('./filters');

for (var i in customModules) {
    if (customModules.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        require('./' + customModules[i]);
    }
}

var nativeModules = [
    'ngSanitize'
];

angular.module('app', customModules.concat(nativeModules));
```

I'm planning on extracting that to it's own module but it'll do for demonstration. For some reason this code throws this exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './controllers'
```

But when I load it using a static string

```
require('./controllers');
```

No problems, everything works and my sample application behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [Browserify Handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook) at [how browserify works](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#how-browserify-works) (emphasis mine):

> Browserify starts at the entry point files that you give it and searches for any require() calls it finds using **static analysis** of the source code's abstract syntax tree.
>
> For every require() call with **a string in it**, browserify resolves those module strings to file paths and then searches those file paths for require() calls recursively until the entire dependency graph is visited.

Bottom line: the dependencies must be statically declared; your code involving the dynamcally-created `require()` calls cannot work (although a good idea in principle).

You could achieve a similar result using server-side or build-time techniques.